# Does any of git hostings allow to make PR across repositories?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, bitbucket, branching-and-merging

[image]I have a need to merge (share) some code between repositories.
I have a core application (core functionality) and I have a lot of similar repositories (just with different styles) but the core functionality is from the core repo.

Currently, I hosted on Bitbucket and there is no ability to create a PR from core repo to another one (once core repo updated I need to merge these changes into rest repositories).

A years ago I worked with VSTS and I remember we used to create a PR between similar repos.

Comment: thats not a feature of git itself - git doesnt know about PRs. github allows you to do that.

Comment: Do you really need a PR? If so, these would have to be forks. But if you just want to _merge_ from one repo to another, that's easy.

Comment: When you say "similar repositories" do you mean copies with slight changes? Like a repo with the generic version and then repos per site or client? Copying changes to each one is a maintenance nightmare. This problem is probably better handled with configuration and dependency management. You can expand your configuration so the "different styles" are just configuration changes. And you can package the shared pieces and depend on them; many package managers will pull dependencies straight from a Git repository.

Comment: Yes, copies with slight changes. I do not need do it so often, I cannot restructure the core functionality into modules, so looking for a variant to share PR.

Answer (score 1):

[GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/) supports merge requests (@ pull requests) from forked repositories into the source repositories, both on the hosted service as well as the installable on-premise solutions.

Here how such a merge request would look like (screenshot from my team's own on-premise repository):

[image: demo merge request from fork]

Refer https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/creating_merge_requests.html#new-merge-request-from-a-fork for more information.

### OR

Are you talking about submodules?, which is a native git feature (regardless of git application server/hosting) in which a repository can have parts of its subfolders to be tracked and managed in a separate repository. Git submodule is a big topic by itself which might be hard to explain within one StackOverflow answer.

You can simply google "git submodule" to find more information about it but here are some websites to kick-start:

- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules
- https://github.blog/2016-02-01-working-with-submodules/

Comment: I'm not talking about submodules. And I'm not sure that forks - my case. Forks are copies of the main repo, work in forks is suppose PR into the main repo.
In my case, I need to merge the code from main repo into other ones.